# Rails forms for adding / removing associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations

I would like to know how to add / remove associations in a form. Lets say I have two models linked by foreign keys

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :participants
end

class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :events
end
```

I have created some forms to edit each model. However, is there a way to use the form to remove/add a participant from/to a lecture? (I guess this would require some javascript to add / remove entries in the view as well as well...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and some js magic. **Ryan Bates** describes this perfectly in some of his free episodes:

[Nested Model Form Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

[Nested Model Form Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)

And [here](https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/tree/master/episode-197/surveysays) is the full source code of this episodes.
Maybe you'll have to adapt some things because it's a little old, for instance replace `link_to_function` for a simple `link_to` with an `:onclick` event, but I think pretty much everything else works on **Rails 4**.

Hope it helps!